# Time complexity of sort by x1, then x2?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o

The standard sort function literature will tell you that a sort can generally (Merge, Quick) be done in `N log N`.

So for instance if I have this list: `[1,6,3,3,4,2]`

It will be sorted in NlogN time to this: `[1,2,3,3,4,6]`

What if I have a list where I sort by the first property, then the second?

Like this: `[(1,1),(6,3),(3,4),(3,1),(2,8)]` to this: `[(1,1),(2,8),(3,1),(3,4),(6,3)]`

What's the time complexity of that?

What I've come up with is that if all the first indices are the same, you're just doing an `N log N` again, so the same. If there's a bunch of different first indices though, you are re-sorting a bunch of little sets.

Comment: The same. Every comparison needs to look at one or two numbers for both elements, so it's still constant time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge sort(or quick sort) performs `O(N log N)` comparisons. Its time complexity is `O(N log N * time_to_compare_two_elements)`. The time complexity of comparing a pair of elements is constants(if the time to compare two element is constant). Thus, the time complexity of sorting an array of pairs is `O(N log N)`, too.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you will be comparing the first elements of each pair and sort.Takes NlogN. Now will compare seconds elements if first elements are same. which takes NlogN. Total 2Nlogn which is nothing but NlogN

Hope this Helps!!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know anything more about your data, you can't guarantee better than `O(N log(N))`: all first elements could be the same, and then you'd be stuck sorting the second elements as normal.

That's what the `O(N log(N))` bound means: if you have to generic-comparison-sort your data, you can't improve on this.  Full stop.

If you *do* have further information, then (as you intuitively reasoned) you might be able to improve on this.  As an example, say that for any `x` that occurs at least once as the first element in a pair, there are roughly `log(N)` pairs having `x` as their first element.  In this case, your first pass can be more efficient:

```
d = {}
for x, y in L:
    xL = d.setdefault(x, [])
    xL.append(y)
xs_sorted = sorted(d.keys())
```

This is (roughly) `O(N)`, since `d.keys()` has `N / log(N)` elements.  Next, you can sort each of the `N / log(N)` sublists, which each have size `log(N)`:

```
L_sorted = []
for x in xs_sorted:
    ys_sorted = sorted(d[x])
    for y in ys_sorted:
        L_sorted.append((x, y))
```

This is `O(N log(log(N)))`, which dominates the runtime - but is better than `O(N log(N))`!

Answer (score 0):

There is a constant factor in Nlog(N) complexity which is dependent how a computer is going to make the comparison before deciding the order. For example if the sorting is on the characters the complexity of Nlog(N) will become

> Nlog(N) * length of maximum string size